# what is best iap unitypackage (Asset) for support google play+ amazon in unity 2019.1.9?

Tags: unity, google-play, in-app-purchase

I need a unitypackage easy and easy for In app purchasing in googleplay and amazon (for Android) Which unitypackage is best in unity 2019.1.9?

Comment: unity has its own packages and are simple to implement. soomla is another option

Comment: Questions asking for package/library/technology recommendations are not on-topic for this site.

Comment: DMGregory♦ ok , But I do not know what use unitypackage????? because In app purchase does not work in google play

Comment: this question shouldn't have been put on hold, it isn't breaking any rules.

Comment: In purchase do work with google play. and alternative to unity IAP is Open IAB from (Google) or soomla. There may be others but i used only these three. I would suggest check all these. Me personally i like Open IAB and Unity IAP.

Comment: Thanks Swati ,I will check them,CA YOu send link soomla and open IAB for download? because UI could ot find them and soomla was not available,is  It active also?